# Building Apache Spark 1.4 with maven : stop building without error

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to build Apache Spark 1.4.0 with maven, the build never ends; it freezes and no error is shown. 
I have no idea why but it freezes on this line :

```
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-launcher_2.10 ---
```

I try to update scala (2.11.4) and Maven (3.0.5) and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building it the way they suggest it?

Which is by running the included ***mvn*** command (see [README](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/README.md#building-spark)).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the mvn command : 'build/mvn -DskipTests clean package' as they suggest it

Comment: then what do you mean when you say you updated to maven 3.0.5?

Comment: I simply install the last Maven version on my computer (I'm working on local) tu be sure that the problem don't come from an oldest version of Maven. It's the same for Scala, i had Scala 2.10 so I upgrade my computer to Scala 2.11.4

Comment: Try a newer maven version (3.2.5 or 3.3.3)